# Finalize method causing performance overhead

Tags: java, performance, methods, finalize

Why is it that implementing finalize method causes performance overhead in Java?

Comment: What source says there is a performance overhead? All objects already have a virtual `finalize` method

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html

Comment: Ah interesting, I didn't realize that objects with finalize overriden would be treated differently by the GC

Comment: @flakes even if overridden with an empty method, it will be added to the finalization queue.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason:

Java postpones GC to almost very late stage - when we are kind of running out of memory - and then quickly clears several 100 MBs or GBs.

The finalize method is designed to run just before a method is GC'ed.

**So, at a critical moment there will be about 10 million objects finalize method being executed!!**

So, the finalize is not the right place to do anything.

The minute you stop using a resource, it has to be closed/released.

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/why-not-to-use-finalize-method-in-java/

Comment: one can still set the `gcInterval` to a lower value (default is once per minute). so you are trying to imply, that you instance & destruct 10 million objects per minute? later version of Java don't even use it anymore. and such unreal number do not add more weight to the claim.

Comment: Most Java programmers are taught to avoid finalize - and OP wants to know why. I am assuming he wants a simple answer.

Comment: The article you posted has a section titled "Finalizers are not your friend".. So, I hope you are not reccommending implementing finalize method in user objects.

Comment: I agree, there may be rare cases where finalize is useful. Just saying don't feel free to implement finnalize in every object OP likes.

Comment: "being taught to" is not exactly the same as "knowing what is actually going on"... while there barely should be heavy code, that would make sense in an implementation of `finalize()`. I mean, the purpose of it always were rare cases.

Comment: Please guess what level of information OP is looking for. If he is an expert looking for intricate details, I am sure, he will ask for more such info. I'm assuming its a beginner question.

Comment: as I see it ...it is a myth being presented as a fact. slowing down the GC does not affect run-time.

Comment: @MartinZeitler The link you shared has a section titled "Finalizers are not your friend"!!

Comment: Apparently finalize method has been deprecated in Java 9 :O

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/java-lang-object-finalize-is-finally-deprecated-f99df40fa71

Comment: I'd agree as far as, that calling `.finalize()` is basically pointless (hence it will be called, no matter what) and that implementing it slows down the GC... which might be both reasons for it having been deprecated.

Comment: NOTE: The Finalization Queue is a linked list so every object added to the finalization queue adds another object.